# Ошибка при проверке email на существование посредством php

Tags: php, сокет, email, smtp

Реализовал проверку email на существование посредством php, вернее модифицировал существующий класс.
В наличие имеются онлайн сервисы, но они не устраивают по разным причинам.

Проверка реализована в следующей последовательности:
1) Verify DNS
2) Verify MX
3) Открываем сокет хоста MX
4) И выполняем последовательно "HELO localhost" -> "MAIL FROM: " -> "RCPT TO: "

Самое странное заключается в том, что для некоторых емайлов, в частности f.biskin@ellica.de, этот метод не срабатывает, выдает

```
HELO localhost
Received response » 554 SMTP synchronization error
```

При проверке посредством telnet все работает, выдает код 2хх.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может, сперва нужно подождать, что выдаст сервер, перед `MAIL FROM`? Сервер может потребовать авторизации, может даже отказать в ее возможности, если не отправить STARTTLS. Сервер mail.ru, например, до последнего говорит, что все ОК, и только после отправки письма сообщает, что такого пользователя и вовсе не существует. То есть, с ESMTP нужно работать последовательно и адекватно, а не HELO и сразу MAIL FROM, такое мое мнение.

Comment: В (E)SMTP конкретно адрес подается далеко после HELO. То есть вы просто пропускаете важные для вашей задачи сообщения сервера. Это мое предположение. Могу быть неправ. Требуется полный лог SMTP-сессии.

Comment: А может этот сервер сразу хочет SSL.

Comment: Ошибка выдается сразу после HELO. А если хочет SSL - как дать? Почему тогда по telnet все работает?

Comment: Может, ему не нравится localhost, но текст ошибки, вроде, об этом не говорит...